# How to output a javascript variable's value inside html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All,

I've a javascript routine which returns a string value, I want to use this routine inside my html tags like this,

```
<a href="#"><script>getKeyValue('empDesignation')</script></a>
```

Is this possible?. Any insights?

Comment: can't you use something like document.write?

Comment: Hi Sam, Can u check see my update latest edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you cant use javascript variables inside html tags. You have to set the value to html by using DHTML.

If you post some code i can help you

Comment: Hi Yorgo, I want to do this without using DHTML. Is there any way available?

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
  <head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function alterText(){
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = empDesignation();
}
  function empDesignation(){   
    var output = 'test'
   return output
  }
</script>

  </head>
  <body onload="javascript:alterText()">

    <a id="hello"></a>

  </body>


  </html>
```

This should work. I had to mock up your empDesignation function.

Comment: Hi Sam, I want to do this without using DHTML. Is there any way available?

Comment: I don't think so. Not if you're getting your value from a javascript function.

I'll add the html into my example if you like.

Answer (score 1):

document.write(getKeyValue('empDesignation'));
This would probably do the trick.

**UPDATE**: It has to be enclosed within `<script>` tags

Comment: Hi Dominik, When I try to write like that, it my javascript menu gets disappeared, and the designation alone gets printed in the browser.

Comment: document.write will erase everything before writing if the page has already been finished loading, innerHTML should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var txt = getKeyValue('empDesignation');
$('#result').text(txt);
```

This assumes that getKeyValue() returns a string. Then you put that the result as text of element with id=result

EDIT - after your edit. you could do

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-key='empDesignation' class='functional'>your text</a>
```

js

```
//when you click on a link that has the class functional    
$('a.functional').on('click', function(e){
  //prevent the default action
  e.preventDefault();
  //retrieve the data that from the html5 data attribute and pass it to 
  //your custom function
  var result = getKeyValue($(this).data('key'));
  //use the resulting string as the new text for the clicked link
  $(this).text(result);
})
```

Comment: Hi Nicoloa, If I do like this, my menu size tends to shrink.

Comment: @EdsonMedina i know i thought it was a user defined function. I added the missing dot

Comment: @EdsonMedina getKeyvalue() is a custom function.

Comment: Thanks Nicoloa!.. Good solution!.. but I'm not dealing the with anchor click events.

Answer (score 0):

inside  html tags this getKeyValue('empDesignation') it is not possible,

use innerHTML like below example

```
           <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(){
        document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = 'is Software Developer';
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <p>Employee Designation <b id='boldStuff'>is what?</b> </p> 
    <input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(){
             var get_des=getKeyValue('empDesignation');

            document.getElementById('change_id').innerHTML = get_des;
    }
    </script>

           <a href="#" id="change_id" onclick='changeText()'></a>
```